# DIV layout floating issue

Tags: css, css-float, html

I am trying to get the contact form on this [page](http://shipping.siteprogression.com/contact-us/) to display on the left and the contact information (the address at the bottom) to display on the right. The divs are both small enough widths that it should not be a problem, and they are both floated to the left. It doesn't seem to be working however. Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

The code is shown below:

```css
#mid {
    width: 793px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    float: right;
    height:auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    border-right: 1px solid gray;
    clear: right;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}

#mid #contact-info  {
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    text-align:left;
    padding:14px;
}

#mid #contact-form  {
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    width:300px!important;
}
```

Comment: why not just float one right, one left?  also post your html so we can see the structure of your page

Comment: remove the empty `<p>` on line 259

Comment: Instead of linking the to the page, you should post the relevant HTML on your post.  Keeping it all together ensures that the question will be coherent for future visitors, especially if the linked page were to go away.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a common parent div and float one left and the other right with specific width.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this...

```css
#mid #contact-info  {
float:right;
width:250px;
text-align:left;
padding:14px;
}

#mid #contact-form  {
float:left;
text-align:left;
width:300px!important;
}
```

But like you say...it should be working how it is....
But without your HTML, we can't really help anymore

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do?

http://jsfiddle.net/R6Mra/

CSS

```css
.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right
}

#parent {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 50%;
}

#box1, #box2 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="right" id="parent">
    <div class="left" id="box1">Hello World!</div>
    <div class="right" id="box2">Hello World!</div>
</div>
```